# Making directed a plotly igraph 3D network in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, plotly, igraph

With this code

```
library(igraph)
library(plotly)


g_df <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5),to = c(2,4,1,4,4,4,4,2))
G <-graph_from_data_frame(g_df)

L <- layout.auto(G,dim=3)

vs <- V(G)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(G))


Nv <- length(vs)
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)

Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]
Zn <- L[,3]

es$breaks <- NA

lines <- data.frame(node=as.vector(t(es)), x=NA, y=NA, z=NA)
lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$x <- Xn[as.integer(lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$node)]
lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$y <- Yn[as.integer(lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$node)]
lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$z <- Zn[as.integer(lines[which(!is.na(lines$node)),]$node)]

network <- plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", x = Xn, y = Yn, z = Zn, 
               mode = "markers",# text = vs$label, hoverinfo = "text", 
               showlegend = F) %>%
add_trace(x=lines$x, y=lines$y, z=lines$z, showlegend = FALSE,
        type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers',
        marker = list(color = '#030303'), line = list(width = 3),
        connectgaps=FALSE)
network
```

I get the graph I want, but by now I have not been able to include arrows (instead normal lines) in order to make the graph directed. The same happens to me with loops.

Does anyone know how to include them? Thanks!

Comment: You have to use `annotations` in `layout`. Make sure to set `text = ''`. If you want it to rotate with the 3d plot, add them within `scene`, like `layout(scene = list(annotations = list....` Check out the [arguments](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-annotations) and [examples](https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/).

Comment: Could you please include an example? I don't get what you say.